# Sorting Values by Second Column Used in Groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {
    'CH': [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
    'Z': [10, 11, 10, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 11, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14],
    'Res': [23, 43, 21, 23, 43, 9, 21, 13, 23, 43, 31, 27, 31, 33, 54, 17, 19, 23, 33]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If I do `df.groupby(['CH', 'Z']).mean()`, I get the following:

[image: Pandas groupby]

I would like to be able to sort the values by the `Z` column in descending order.

I'd also like to sort values by the values in the `Res` column too, but the first is most important.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `[![Pandas groupby][1]][1]` in your example? Do you want to sort after the groupby?

Comment: Picture didn't show up, let me repost it

Comment: To sort values of `Z` in descending order `df.sort_values(by='Z', ascending=False)`

Answer (score 1):

This sorts first by 'Z', and then by 'Res'

```
dfs = df.groupby(['CH', 'Z']) \
          .mean() \
          .reset_index() \
          .sort_values(['Z', 'Res'], ascending=False)
```

If it's necessary to preserve the multi-index similar to the groupby result:

```
dfs.set_index(['CH', 'Z'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values` since `pandas.DataFrame.sort` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html).

```
df.groupby(['CH', 'Z']).mean().sort_values(by='Z', ascending=False)
```

If you're going to sort by `Res`, just change the value passed to the `by` parameter,

```
df.groupby(['CH', 'Z']).mean().sort_values(by='Res')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) in the groupby statement which will retain the index and sort them without having to use `set_index()`:

```
df_res=df.groupby(['CH', 'Z']).mean().sort_values('Res',ascending=False).sort_index(level=1,ascending=False)
print(df_res)

       Res
CH Z       
1  14 33.00
0  14 28.33
1  13 23.00
0  13 29.00
1  12 38.50
0  12 13.00
1  11 38.00
0  11 26.00
1  10 31.00
0  10 17.67
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to sort the values by the `Z` column... then
>   by `Res`.

To clear up some terminology: `Z` is an **index level**, while `Res` is a **series**. Pandas, via [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), helps hide this distinction. Just specify the `ascending` argument to align with the components you wish to sort by:

```
res = df.groupby(['CH', 'Z']).mean()\
        .sort_values(['Z', 'Res'], ascending=[False, True])

print(res)

             Res
CH Z            
0  14  28.333333
1  14  33.000000
   13  23.000000
0  13  29.000000
   12  13.000000
1  12  38.500000
0  11  26.000000
1  11  38.000000
0  10  17.666667
1  10  31.000000
```